# JavaFX bar progress wont go higher than 0.1

Tags: java, javafx

I use this:

```
@FXML
private ProgressBar bar;

@FXML
protected void addBar() {
    double a = 0.0;
    a += 0.1;
    bar.setProgress(a);
}
```

That code executes when the bar is clicked but the progress bar and the double wont go higher than 0.1. But i'm adding a value of 0.1 everytime you click it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime you initialize value of `a` to `0.1` so it will always be `0.1` thats why you are not able to increment it. You should take `a` as a global variable and should increment it rather than putting it in  `addBar()` function.